# How to use HTML tags on other tags in Shiny?

Tags: html, shiny, tags

I am trying to print a title like :

There is **45%** available

With **45%** in bold like that, and I produced this code :

```
h4(paste0("There is ", strong(as.character(prctnage)), strong("%"), " available"))
```

Here is the output :

`There is <strong>45<strong><strong>%<strong> available`

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `?h4`: ...  arguments expect:

> Tag attributes (named arguments) and children (unnamed arguments)

In your example `paste0` in `h4` converts the tags to a string.

```
library(shiny)
library(htmltools)

percentage <- 10

ui <- fluidPage(
  h4("There is ", strong(paste0(percentage, "%")), " available"),
  # another option:
  h4(HTML(paste0("There is ", strong(as.character(percentage)), strong("%"), " available")))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}
```

shinyApp(ui, server)

[image: result]

Another option would be to mark the characters as HTML again using `HTML()`